# How can avoid repeat same where in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

In my project I don't use a physical delete, I just use logical "soft delete" for all tables.

I use this clause for all queries:

```
.Where(row => row.IsDeleted == false)
```

I want a way to avoid to repeat this `where` clause in all queries.

I have method like this to get data :

```
public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
{
    return base.Set<TEntity>();
}
```

and I call it like this :

```
_categories = _uow.Set<Category>();
```

How can I do this ?

**First Idea:**

Add a base class and put `Deleted` column in that and inherit all classes from this base class. Is this a good way?

I use `UnitOfWork` and code-first.

Comment: Don't you think it would be "safer" to explicitly filter your records instead of the data layer magically _swallowing_ some of your data? Especially if multiple people are/will be working on this code. I imagine it would be very hard to get to the bottom of an unexpected behavior caused by this.

Comment: I think If  I use `where ` in all query in `Service` Layer , It may be a place where I forget and its a bug for system  , and Repeat a code in software engineering is not good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not be creating a base class only for the sake of reuse a single property. Instead, I would create an interfase and an extension method to encapsulate and reuse  the `where` statement. Something like the following:

```
public static class EntityFrameworkExtentions
{
    public static ObservableCollection<TEntity> Alive<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> set)
        where TEntity : class, ISoftDeleteAware
    {
        var data = set.Where(e => e.IsDeleted == false);
        return new ObservableCollection<TEntity>(data);
    }
}
```

The interface declaration

```
public interface ISoftDeleteAware
{
    bool IsDeleted { get;set;}
}
```

Usage:

```
var coll = DbContext.Categories.Alive();
```

Comment: I this this Asnwer its better for my project and my Arcitcture .

Answer (score 2):

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal MyContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(MyContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetNonDeleted(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        query = query.Where(row => row.IsDeleted == false);

        return query;
    }
    // Other methods
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you never delete anything, then you can use base entity class and IsDelete property with it. After, use this base entity for Generic Repository. It looks like;

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    public BaseModel()
    {
        IsDelete = false;
        CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsDelete{ get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
}

 public class YourClassHere : BaseModel
{
    //
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseModel
{
    private readonly IDbContext _context;
    private IDbSet<T> _entities;

    public Repository(IDbContext context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public T GetByIdByIgnoringDeleteStatus(int id)
    {
        return this.Entities.Find(id);
    }

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return this.Entities.Single(item => item.Id == id && !item.IsDelete);           

    }

    public void Create(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
            }
            entity.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
            this.Entities.Add(entity);                
            //this._context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            var msg = string.Empty;

            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    msg += string.Format("Property: {0} Error: {1}",
                    validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage) + Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }

            var fail = new Exception(msg, dbEx);
            throw fail;
        }
    }

    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
            }
            entity.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
            this._context.SetModified(entity);
            //this._context.SaveChanges();

        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            var msg = string.Empty;
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    msg += Environment.NewLine + string.Format("Property: {0} Error: {1}",
                    validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            var fail = new Exception(msg, dbEx);
            throw fail;
        }
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
            }
            entity.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
            this.Entities.Remove(entity);                
            //this._context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            var msg = string.Empty;

            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    msg += Environment.NewLine + string.Format("Property: {0} Error: {1}",
                    validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            var fail = new Exception(msg, dbEx);
            throw fail;
        }
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {           
        return this.Entities;            
    }

    private IDbSet<T> Entities
    {
        get
        {
            if (_entities == null)
            {
                _entities = _context.Set<T>();
            }
            return _entities;
        }
    }

}
```

Now, you can use your class methods with Delete Status.